# What is the correct method to deploy a Laravel/Vue application using Forge with MIX local/production environment variables

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-forge, inertiajs

I understand the process of local > staging > production deployment, although I've come across one issue which I have a solution, but it doesn't feel like it's the correct method.

I have a production `.env` on the server and a local `.env` for local development which is all fine for storing my environment variables. Although, I am using Stripe API and have testing API keys locally and live API keys for production.

My Stripe public key gets pulled into `public.app.js` the Vue/Inertia compilation using the `MIX_` prefix in my `.env`. I first push this to GitHub and then Deploy this to Laravel Forge where in my deploy script it runs `yarn prod`, pulling in the live Stripe public API key once compiled by the server.

Basically, what I am asking is: Is there a standard deployment process where you compile production ready files locally pulling the correct API keys and push to GitHub, or is there a better way which removes the need of compiling assets on the server?

Comment: I don't know if there is a standard, but this is what I suggest is to use ```yarn prod``` before pushing. Use the NODE_ENV var to switch between API keys while compiling. Then push and deploy.

Comment: I was thinking this. So rather than have my public Stripe key in my .env, just put it within the .js file and use NODE_ENV to swap it based on dev/prod.

Comment: you can use it in the .env file. Node can swap between them with a condition. I'm not sure what you are using, but in the package.json file, when you use ```npm run dev``` or ```npm run prod```, a node set a variable ex: ```"production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"```. You can then use it during compiling to take the right token into your .env file.